# How do I create a confirmation pop-up before purchase?

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.2, popup

I want a pop-up to show with a message after the user clicks **PROCEED TO CHECKOUT**.

So the process goes like:

1. User clicks **PROCEED TO CHECKOUT**
2. Pop-up shows with the message with **AGREE** or **DISAGREE** buttons
3. If **DISAGREE**d, close pop-up, and do not do anything, stays in the same page
4. If **AGREEd**, redirect to checkout

PS: I do not need this information to go through backend somewhere, because this message has to be agreed to by all customers, no exception, so I will assume that if the order is placed, then the customer agreed to this message.

PS 2: I know I could place this message in html body, but for our business, this condition is so important I want to create a popup for it.

I'm using Magento 2.2.5 with PHP 7.1

Where should I start?

Answer (score 1):

Copy file from vendor directory

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/default.js
```

to your custom created theme

```
app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/payment/default.js
```

Now, search for find **placeOrder: function (data, event)** and edit this function as given below

```
if(confirm("Are you sure to place order?") == true){
    //default function code
}else{
    return false;
}
```

For example:

```
placeOrder: function (data, event) {

    if(confirm("Are you sure to place order?") == true){
        var self = this;

        if (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }

        if (this.validate() && additionalValidators.validate()) {
            this.isPlaceOrderActionAllowed(false);

            this.getPlaceOrderDeferredObject()
                .fail(
                    function () {
                        self.isPlaceOrderActionAllowed(true);
                    }
                ).done(
                    function () {
                        self.afterPlaceOrder();

                        if (self.redirectAfterPlaceOrder) {
                            redirectOnSuccessAction.execute();
                        }
                    }
                );

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
},
```

After compltion run **php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f** command.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for your answer! Will try this tomorrow and will make sure to comeback here to upvote if it works